# How to deploy Ignite Service from Thick client or Thin client?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Firstly, is there anyway to deploy Ignite service from Thick or Thin client(doesn’t make sense) ? I tried to deploy service locally at runtime and all works but the real server is started from a Batch file in another machine. We do many developments in C# include developing Service classes, So I am not sure how a C# service can be deployed from another machine to the server. I’ve gone through deploying service via config file but not sure How C# assembly can be configured? Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can deploy services from Thick client:

```
IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start(...);
IServices services = ignite.GetServices();
services.Deploy("my-service", new MyService());
```

Requirements:

- Servers must be .NET nodes, **started with Apache.Ignite.exe** or from your own .NET binary that does `Ignition.Start()`.
- Assembly with the `MyService` class must be loaded on all server nodes (with `--assembly` command line argument, with reflection, etc).

It is possible to deploy services from thin client indirectly, using an existing service as a proxy.

Comment: Thank you. As per the requirements, it looks like not possible as our ignite server is build from C++ and running via batch file. Please let me know if you've any advise in this case.

Comment: As you mentioned Servers must be .Net nodes, in this case, can I start a node in client mode (thick client) and deploy service to the same node?

Comment: @JustinMathew who is going to call this service? Other clients? Can you please describe the use case in more detail - why the servers are in C++, etc.

Comment: – Here is the full details. I work in the quant team for an investment bank. The quant libraries are fully in C++ and we’re publishing data into Ignite cache from C++ using C++ thin client. But, we’ve other C# applications which read data for the UI pricing tools and Data view tools. So, in high level, the data publishing part is in C++ and subscribing(or reading) part in C#. At this setup, we would like to know is there anyway a C# service can be deployed or not?. Thank you so much for your help so far, and let us know your advice.

Comment: @JustinMathew yes, in this scenario you can deploy C# services. The only requirement is to use .NET server nodes as described above. This will not affect C++ part in any way.

Comment: I am not sure the current ignite server can be changed to .NET server nodes as the current setup already in production. As a last try, Can i start a .NET node in client mode and deploy .NET service to the same node? not sure it make any sense

Comment: Deploying a service to the same node does not make much sense. Btw, do you have only one Ignite server?

Comment: At present, we've only one server in production but we've other DEV and UAT servers.

Comment: Interesting, Ignite is supposed to be used in a cluster of multiple servers.

Comment: That’s not a problem. We can quickly provision another server and add into cluster. With our current setup, is it possible to add a new .NET node into the current cluster (with other C++ node)

Comment: Yes, you can mix different nodes in one cluster. Then you can do things like `ignite.GetCluster().ForDotNet().GetServices().Deploy(...)`.